# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser - App Crash (code 1073741855)

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Im new to the ChromiumWebBrowser and trying to get a simple example to work, but im unable to do so, and hoping that somebody could point me into the right direction.
My code is as follows:

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(@"http://www.google.com")
{
      Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};
```

The strange thing is that the Example that you download from the CefSharp site works like a charm, but my app crashes.
Debugging revealed an Infinite Loop (or so it seems).

Anybody else seen anything like this before?

Regards
Jean Smit

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Me again :)

Reviewing the debug.log showed the following error:
Couldn't mmap [PROJECT_LOCATION]\bin\Debug\icudtl.dat

I copied that file across from the example to my app and the error is gone.

Regards
Jean